# clear TextInput value on button click - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native and I have these functions. `renderInputs()` generates some inputs fields while `getNextWord()` does some things which are not relevant and moreover it updates the states.

```
getNextWord() {
   // do some stuff    
   this.setState({ set states here }); 
}

renderInputs() {
    var products = []
    // some code that generates a randomNumber
    for (let p = 0; p < randomNumber; p++){
       products.push (<TextInput defaultValue="" maxLength={1} key={p}  onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange(text, p)}></TextInput> );
    }
    return products
}
```

In my `render()` method I show the input fields and I placed I button that everytime is clicked it triggers `getNextWord()` function.

```
<View>{this.renderInputs()}</View>
<Button onPress={this.getNextWord.bind(this)}>Get Next Word</Button>
```

Now, I can correctly see the input fields, and everytime I click on "Get Next Word" button `renderInputs()` generates a new bunch of input fields.

My problem is that if I type a character inside one of these input field once I click button I still see that letter, while I'd like to have all my input fields empty at the beginning.

I tried using `defaultValue=""` but it seems it doesn't work. 
If I do: `defaultValue="A"` this is what I get once I run the app.

**example:**

First time `renderInputs()` is called:

_ _ _ _ _ _  // empty inputs (let's say `randomNumber` is 6)

then I type in the second input field a letter, let's say "G"

_ G _ _ _ _

once I click "Get Next Word" button `renderInputs()` generates `randomNumber` (let's say generated randomNumber is 8) input fields and this is what I get:

A G A A A A A A

but I want to have:

A A A A A A A A

Answer (score 1):

Here's my complete solution, followed by an explanation:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  // initial state
  state = {
    inputsNumber: this.randomInputs()
  }

  getNextWord() {
    // do some stuff
    const nextInputNumber = this.randomInputs()
    const inputsState = {}

    // set all inputs to A
    for (let p = 0; p < nextInputNumber) {
      inputsState[this.inputKey(p)] = 'A'
    }
    // set new random number of inputs
    this.setState({
      ...inputsState
      inputsNumber: nextInputNumber,
      // set rest of state here if needed ...
    });
  }

  renderInputs() {
    var products = []
    // some code that generates a randomNumber
    for (let p = 0; p < this.state.inputsNumber; p++){
       products.push(
        <TextInput
          maxLength={1}
          key={p}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange(text, p)}
          value={ this.state[this.inputKey(p)]}
        />
      );
    }
    return products
  }

  handleChange (text, p) {
    this.setState({
      [this.inputKey(p)]: text
    })
  }

  randomInput () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1 // or whatever random function
  }

  inputKey (p) {
    return 'input ' + p
  }
}
```

First thing first:
I don't think u want to generate the random number in the render function. This means every time [render will get called](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), the number of inputs would change, and that would lead to a very bad UX, since render (potentially) gets called on every state change. So use the state to keep track of that number:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class MyComponent extends Component {

  // initial state
  state = {
    inputsNumber: this.randomInputs()
  }

  getNextWord() {
     // do some stuff
     this.setState({
      inputsNumber: this.randomInputs(),
      // set rest of state ...
    }); 
  }

  randomInput () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1 // or whatever random function
  }
}
```

Now to use your inputs correctly u need to [bound their values to the state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) as well:

```
renderInputs() {
  var products = []
  for (let p = 0; p < this.state.inputsNumber; p++){
     products.push(
      <TextInput
        maxLength={1}
        key={p}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange(text, p)}
        value={this.state[this.inputKey(p)]}
      />
    );
  }
  return products
}

handleChange (text, p) {
  this.setState({
    [this.inputKey(p)]: text
  })
}

inputKey (p) {
  return 'input ' + p
}
```

Now to "reset" all inputs to the letter A, we need to do a slight modification to the click event:

```
getNextWord() {
  // do some stuff
  const nextInputNumber = this.randomInputs()
  const inputsState = {}

  // set all inputs to A
  // since we don't know how many inputs we have, we use the 'nextInputNumber' we just generated.
  for (let p = 0; p < nextInputNumber) {
    inputsState[this.inputKey(p)] = 'A'
  }
  // set new random number of inputs
  this.setState({
    ...inputsState
    inputsNumber: nextInputNumber,
    // set rest of state here if needed ...
  });
}
```

NOTE: I havent tested this. If something doesn't work, create a fiddle and I will modify it to a working example

Comment: Thank you for your time and the answer, finally I solved it using the method clear(0)

Comment: I'm guessing u r new to programming and SO :) I have no idea what `clear(0)` means. Glad u found a solution!